# Include on page once in Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

using template toolkit I have come up with the below. (I am running this template multiple times on the one page.)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
</tr>
[% FOREACH t = Testing %]
    [% IF t.isEven %]
    <tr><td>Goodbye World</td></tr>
    [% ELSE %]
    <tr><td>hello world</td></tr>

    size() = [% loop.size %]</br>
    max () = [% loop.max %]</br>
    index () = [% loop.index %]</br>
    count () = [% loop.count %]</br>
    first () = [% loop.first %]</br>
    last () = [% loop.last %]</br>
    prev () = [% loop.prev %]</br>
    next () = [% loop.next %]</br>

    [% END %]
[% END %]
</table>
[% myJS %]
```

which outputs this. (i only included the first and last tr in here to save space).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
<tr class="1"><td>hello world</td></tr>
size() = 5</br>
max () = 4</br>
index () = 0</br>
count () = 1</br>
first () = 1</br>
last () = 0</br>
prev () = </br>
next () = HASH(0x1d6daad0)</br>

<tr class="4"><td>hello world</td></tr>
size() = 5</br>
max () = 4</br>
index () = 4</br>
count () = 5</br>
first () = 0</br>
last () = 1</br>
prev () = HASH(0x1cbfda20)</br>
next () = HASH(0x1d6e9c10)</br>
</table>
<script src ="js/my.js"></script><table>
```

over and over until my loop is finished.  Is there a way to only include [% myJS %] on the page once? as it is the same script?

Comment: It only appears in the output once. (And your HTML needs the attention of a [validator](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: @Quentin It shows <table></table><script> over and over I didn't include it all as it ended up being long.  I am not concerned about the html at this point I simply outputed the loop iterators to see if they can help me, they will be removed,

Comment: I don't get what the problem is, either. Post more output. Otherwise we cannot see what you mean.

Comment: I think it's likely that your `</table>` and `[% myJS %]` tags were mistakenly inside your loop `[% END %]` block.  There's no reason it would be repeated otherwise (based on the limited code you've provided)

Comment: @BrianPhillips thanks I have reviewed my code and I am running the template multiple times on the page. so [% myJS %] is running once per template, which is unnecessary is there a way to say only display on the page once regardless of how many times it is run in a template?

Comment: @simbabque I have edited the question to give more information, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you have shown us here only displays the my.js line once. It is outside of any loop so it can't possibly be displayed more than once.

If you're getting it displayed more than once, then you're not using the code that you are showing us. Or there is more code surrounding the code in your example. Do you perhaps have another loop which displays multiple tables?

In general, the solution to your problem would be to move the code which displays the Javascript file outside of any loops - so it only displays once. If, however, that's not an option for some reason (and I really can't see why it wouldn't be) then you can use the loop variable to only output the Javascript on the first (or, perhaps, the last) iteration of the loop. Something like this:

```
[% FOR var IN list;
     var.something_useful;
     myJS IF loop.first;
   END %]
```

Comment: Agreed, I think he mispelled an end tag or something.

Comment: You are right it is only displaying once, I have confused myself as the template is on the page multiple times. I have added more info to the question thanks.